# Element XMLFileDefinition is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList

Tags: java, xml, coldfusion

Here is a simplified example which creates an identical error to the one that I am trying to fix.

```
<cfscript>
    private xml function getBaseRequest() {
        // Set up the root xml element
        var xmlReturn = XmlNew(true);
        xmlReturn.xmlRoot = xmlElemNew(xmlReturn,'testbase');

        // Attach a child with generic name
        ArrayAppend(xmlReturn['testbase'].XmlChildren,xmlElemNew(xmlReturn,'thisworks'));

            // Add a child to that
            ArrayAppend(xmlReturn['testbase']['thisworks'].XmlChildren,xmlElemNew(xmlReturn,'attachme'));

        // Now attach a child with node name 'XMLFileDefinition'
        ArrayAppend(xmlReturn['testbase'].XmlChildren,xmlElemNew(xmlReturn,'XMLFileDefinition'));

            // And attempt to add a child to that
            // produces error "Element XMLFileDefinition is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList"
            ArrayAppend(xmlReturn['testbase']['XMLFileDefinition'].XmlChildren,xmlElemNew(xmlReturn,'thisbreaks'));

        return xmlReturn;
    }
</cfscript>
```

To clarify, the XML when dumped out just before the line marked as erroring is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testbase>
    <thisworks>
        <attachme/>
    </thisworks>
    <XMLFileDefinition/>
</testbase>
```

Unfortunately this XML is required according to a schema provided by a third party and as such we cannot have the nodes renamed to something that works more nicely with ColdFusion.

**UPDATE** this seems to be related to the "XML" prefix on the node name.  Any node that prefixes with "XML" seems to cause this problem.  I have added my answer detailing how I got around this however hoping someone can come up with a more elegant/universal solution as mine has some potential pitfalls.

Versions of CF/Java as follows :

- ColdFusion version : 9,0,1,274733
- Java version : 14.3-b01

I have also tried updating and this still occurs on the following versions

- ColdFusion version : 9,0,1,274733 (Cumulative Hotfix 2)
- Java version : 1.7.0_03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following further investigation I determined that this issue is caused by attempting to access an XML node whose name matches the REGEX 'xml.*' (i.e. starts with the letters xml, in any case.)  I was unable to identify a specific explanation though I would assume this relates to the Xml.... keys that are used to refer to XmlAttributes/XmlChildren/XmlText etc

The method I eventually used to fix this are as follows (truncated example)

```
var xmlReturn = XmlNew(true);
var nodeBody = xmlElemNew(xmlReturn,'RootElement');
xmlReturn.xmlRoot = nodeBody;

var nodeXMLDefinition = xmlElemNew(xmlReturn,'XMLFileDefinition');
    ArrayAppend(nodeXMLDefinition.XmlChildren, xmlElemNew(xmlReturn,'SomeChildElement'));
ArrayAppend(nodeBody.XmlChildren,nodeXMLDefinition);
```